# Rpm failed when installing various files

Tags: linux, centos, rpm

I am using a Centos 5 machine to create several RPMS and I have the next problem:

Whenever I try to install them one by one, everything goes fine. However, when I install them all at once (with *), an error arises:

(consider all my rpm files begin with the name "FILE-").

```
rpm -ivh --force FILE-*
```

The error:

```
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /path/to/my/file.jar;58e4ab6b: cpio open failed - No such file or directory
error: FILE-myfile.noarch: install failed
```

This error   appears **only with the second file, and so on**. The first file is **always** installed correctly.

One more thing. I pack all rpms in a Centos 5 machine (rpm version 4.4.2.3) and try to install them in a Centos 7 machine (rpm version 4.11.3).

Comment: Why are you trying centos-5 rpms in a centos-7 box ? That's going to create a lot other problem !

Comment: I was having a similar problem this morning and found that my rpm wanted to create a symbolic link from one directory to another, but there already existed a real directory (not a symbolic link) with the second directory name. For instance, the rpm would try to ln -s /opt/fish/bin /opt/fish/depbin, when an /opt/fish/depbin already existed as a directory. In my case, it was trying to install on an "unclean" test system, but in your case, the first rpm (that succeeds) is likely creating the conflicting condition.

Comment: The thing is that the installation does work when intalling them one by one, in the same order